# Form Closing event

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, mobile

I have a smartdevice project targeting windows mobile 6.
In the top right corner is an X (provided by the controlbox). i have an event on the form_closing that i was hoping would fire when the cross is clicked. But it doesnt :-(

Does anyone know why this event is not firing ???

Thanks  :-)
John

Answer (score 7):

Set the `MinimizeBox` property of your form to `false`.  It's a weird thing about WinMo forms, but the `X` in the corner is really a minimize button, so it doesn't actually close the form.  Setting `MinimizeBox` to `false` will replace the `X` with an `OK` button, and you'll get the form closing event.

Comment: @johnm01: you're welcome. You can go ahead and select this as the correct answer (click the check mark next to this answer).

Answer (score 1):

Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx

Answer (score -2):

There are a number of possible reasons why theis could be happening, but I seriously doubt anyone will be able to guess why in this case, without you letting us see any of your code?